# How to reset Secure Function Password on a Brother MFC-9560-CDW

Tags: password-recovery, brother-printer

We set up the Secure Function Password feature on a Brother MFC-9560-CDW multi-function printer, and then forgot the password.

How do we reset the password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **WARNING**
>   This procedure will perform a factory reset.  All configuration settings will be lost.

Ignoring the display, press in rapid succession <kbd>Menu</kbd> <kbd>Start</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd>

The display should read

> MAINTENANCE MODE

Press <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>

The display should read

> PARAMETER INIT

Press <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd>

The printer should reboot.
At this point the printer should be reset to factory defaults.

Comment: Just to be clear for anyone else who may be wondering the "Start" button you press needs to be the black one if you have a color laser printer. Also this works on the MFC-9120CN and other similar brother printers! :)