# How to reset the Secure Function for Brother DCP 9020 CDW

Tags: network-printer, reset, brother-printer

I have a Brother DCP 9020CDW has been locked with the function lock and I do not have the password.

The interface is different than for the MFC-9560-CDW. So [this answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/689762/how-to-reset-secure-function-password-on-a-brother-mfc-9560-cdw) doesn't help me much.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question.

I called Brother Support. The recipe for a factory reset (*thou will loose all settings*) is as follows:

1. Press the lightened *home* icon for about 5 seconds.

On the display you will see 4 bars, the top ones indicating some details about the printer, the lower ones being empty.

2. Now press and hold the lowest bar for a few seconds.

A numeric touch pad will appear in the display screen.

3. Type `*2864` on the numerical pad that appears.

This will get you in maintenance mode.

5. Press `01`

The printer will display `parameter init` for a short while and then `maintenance` again.

6. Type `99`

The printer will reset, and the process is complete.